# Paypal Merchant php sdk: error running samples

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

I downloaded the merchant php paypal sdk, version 3.6.106, and I'm having some troubles installing it and running samples. On github page they says composer is not necessary and we can use install.php. But where is install.php? I did not find it here https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/tree/stable-php5.3

I tried to use the install.php from 2.X version but I have the following error:  mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PayPal\CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType' not found in /var/www/merchant-sdk/samples/ExpressCheckout/DGsetExpressCheckout.php

Thanks in advance.